# Sorting the references in alphabetically in chronological order according to authors last name

Tags: bibtex, natbib, sorting

i have submitted a paper to Elsevier Journal (Information Sciences). The editor has told me to sort the entries (references) in alphabetical order according to authors last name. I searched a lot but the information i got from various site does not match my requirement.  I tried all the 8 .bst styles provided by Elsevier and also plain, abbrv, alpha etc. but no success. I am using bibtex and my bib database is ref (citations are taken from googlescholar using MLA and bibtex). I have used

```
\begin{document}
\bibliography{ref} 
\bibliographystyle{model1-num-names.bst}%used all other .bst of elsevier but in vain.

\end {document}
```

The reference style i want to obtain is

> [1] S. **Agrawal**, Y. Dodis, V. Vaikuntanathan, et al., On continual leakage of discrete log representations, in: K. Sako, P. Sarkar (Eds.), Proceedings of ASIACRYPT 2013, 8270, LNCS, 2013, pp. 401–420.
>
> [2] A. **Akavia**, S. Goldwasser, C. Hazay, Distributed public key schemes secure against continual leakage, in: Proceedings of the 2012 ACM Symposium on
>    Principles of Distributed Computing (PODC’12), pp. 155–164.
>
> [3] A. **Astle**, S. Goldwasser, V. Vaikuntanathan, Simultaneous hardcore bits and cryptography against memory attacks, in: O. Reingold (Ed.), Proceedings
>    of the 6th Theory of Cryptography Conference (TCC 2009), 5444, LNCS, 2009, pp. 474–495.

In tex, these references are randomly distributed say, 1, 10, 23 etc. But in the reference section, they need to appear based on the alphabetical order of the authors last name.

May i know if i am missing anything? I tried with `natbib` package as well but in vain.

Comment: `\bibliographystyle{plain}`?

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a complete, compilable example rather than fragments of code.